# Break the loop after the fourth ++ or --

Tags: java, loops

How can I break the loop after the fourth step?
I have to stop the loop after the fourth step.

```
i=200; i > 0; i = i - 17
```

Comment: Simple : use `break;`

Comment: have a counter outside of loop and increment it inside. Simply put a condition if counter equals to 4 `break` out of loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer so far ... miss one key point: why would you want to use two loops?

```
int initialCount = 200;
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
   initialCount -= 17;
```

Please note: of course this means: there is only one loop; and you loose control over the "i > 0" aspect; but hey: you know you are starting with 200; and you know that 200 - 4*17 ... is still >= 0.

Long story short: consider carefully how many loops you really need; as such nested loop structures are typically not helping in terms of "readability" of code. And of course: do not forget to write proper unit tests; so that you can refactor your code in order to find the most suitable representation; whilst being sure that the intended functionality is still preserved.

And lets go beyond that: you already seem to know that you have these constraints:

```
i=200
decrease by 17
do that 4 times
```

So, just to be sure: there are some other things in the background you didn't tell us about; so your program can't be rewritten to

```
i = 200 - (4 * 17)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You could define an additional variable inside the loop and include it inside your loop condition. This way your loop will allways terminate after 4 steps.
example:

```
for(int i = 200, j = 0; i > 0 && j<4; i = i - 17, ++j ) {
    System.out.println("Step " + (j+1) + " i=" + i);
}
```

output:

```
Step 1 i=200
Step 2 i=183
Step 3 i=166
Step 4 i=149
```